# Convergence of this improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How might I show whether $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac {x\sin x} {e^{x^3}} dx$$ converges?

Since this integrand is hard to integrate, are there standard tests (from Complex Analysis or Real Analysis) to merely show convergence/non-convergence?

Comment: Observe that without the $\sin x$ factor it clearly converges.

Comment: $$\dfrac{x\sin x}{e^{x^3}} = O(e^{-x})$$ wich is clearly convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{x\sin x}{e^{x^3}}\right|\le\frac{x}{e^{x^3}}\le\frac{1}{x^2}\ldots$$

Comment: Thks, would you mind to explain the final step? So to check convergence of improper integrals, if the integrand is integrable (by continuity for instance), and if the integrand is bounded by a function whose integral (on the same domain of integration) is bounded, then we can conclude that the given integrand is also bounded, correct?

Comment: Well, I just chose a function which is clearly integrable on $\,[1,\infty)\,$ and that happens to be greater than ours...It's trivial to show that $$x\ge 1\implies x^3\le e^{x^3}$$

Comment: If a function is said to be integrable on $[1,\infty)$, is that understood to mean convergent too on $[1,\infty)$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, @Ryan: that a function's integrable on an infinite interval means its *improper* integral over that integral converges...

Comment: Yes I just wanted to be very sure. Thks!